Connecting a mains electric immersion water heater directly to a low voltage DC supply?
Can I connect a mains electric immersion water heater directly to a low voltage DC supply?
I have acquired some 2nd hand electric solar panels, and I’m looking for a low budget way to heat water. My home already has an indirect, vented hot water cylinder warmed via the gas central heating. The tank also has a currently unused 220 V 3 kW immersion heater – (I think it was installed just to plug the hole in the tank) it’s similar to this one
The immersion heater is rated 3 kW at 220 V, this indicates a maximum current of 13.6 A and a resistance of about 16 Ω. The solar panels are 12 V (nominal) 100 W. Peak voltage 20.2 V, open circuit voltage 24.5 V short circuit current 4.95 A, maximum current 5.2 A.
If I wire the four panels in series, I should get about 80 V at 5 A – which is well within the limits of the immersion heater. Although the heater was designed for 220 V operation, AFAIK it’s basically just length of resistance wire with a bi-metallic strip for temperature control and a click-to-reset thermal cut out for over-temperature protection. As far as I can tell there’s no electronics and nothing that’s voltage-sensitive in the heater?
I’m looking for a low budget way to use the panels. The panels were free, the hot water cylinder is already installed and plumbed in, the immersion heater isn’t in use. Is connecting the panels directly to the heater safe and sensible? I don’t want charge batteries, so don’t need a MPPT controller, nor do I want to run any electrical items so don’t need an inverter. 400 W for 4-5 hours during a day won't give me a full tank of hot water, but should take the edge off the gas bills.
UPDATE in response to comments/answers.
The contacts in the thermostat and safety cut-out are both designed for 220v AC, not 80v DC, so there are valid concerns that these will fail if they have to do much switching. In mitigation however, the tank contains over 120 liters of water so even if I get five full hours of sunshine in a day (unlikely where I live) and even if the panels really are giving 100watts each, then the water is unlikely to get more than 20 degrees (centigrade) warmer, and the thermostat isn't that likely to switch off, and the safety cut-out is even less likely to trip.
Low power solar immersion heaters are actually available, but they don't bother with a built in thermostat or cut out, presumably they rely on external electronics to do the switching and sensing. Unfortunately they use a different thread size so aren't suitable on a domestic HW tank.

Does the immersion heater have any thermal cutout, thermostat or similar built in or is it just a resistor?

The thermostat and cut-out are intended, and rated, to operate on AC, not DC. DC is harder to switch, given the lack of convenient zero crossings. Your planned use is somewhat lower than the AC rating but not especially low so the contacts may arc and weld shut over time. You would need to check the DC rating is adequate but you are unlikely to find this listed for an AC immersion heater.

with a bi-metallic strip for temperature control and a click-to-reset thermal cut out for over-temperature protection.
The bi-metallic strip and thermal cut out are not suitable or safe.
The thermal element can be matched to your panels, and actually, you can buy a thermal element of any particular value, from China, for not much more than the price of post and delivery.
You can make the system safe by forcing the current to zero so that the temperature control and safety work as designed. The easy way to do this is with an inverter, and if you use an inverter you already know that the element is matched to the voltage you are using.
Hot water tanks are dangerous enough to be interesting, and only made safe by multiple safety features, all of which have to fail before someone is killed. The bottom of the tank is deliberately weakened, so that when the tank explodes, it rockets up in the air, and lands a block away, instead of exploding sideways and taking out a wall of your house. But it only explodes if the pressure relief valve has seized up. But it doesn't get hot enough to spray out of the pressure relief valve, because the thermal cut out has disconnected the power, which shouldn't matter because the temperature control hasn't let it get that hot.
But the thermal cut out and the temperature control only work with AC power, because they are designed to disconnect as the current goes through zero 100 or 120 times a second.
I know that's kind of discouraging, but apart from the safety aspect, the temperature control really won't work correctly with DC. Even if it seems to work at first, it will fail soon and then not work at all.
It's not actually a requirement to use a sine-wave inverter at 50-60 Hz. Purpose built systems normally just use a current interrupt of some sort, and generally at a higher frequency. It doesn't matter because it's just going into the resister, it doesn't have to be shaped, just interrupted to limit arcing.
FWIW, you can buy a correctly designed system like you describe, but it's not cheap. The actual system cost is maybe 10% of what you pay: the rest of the money is going to pay for the safety approvals required for electrical hot water systems. If there was a big demand, that overhead could be paid by high-volume sales, and the price would  collapse to something reasonable, but as it is, it's a niche product that nobody can make a profit on.

It is pretty simple. I've made controller you are looking for and it succefuly runs third year. My topology consist of H-bridged four MOSFETs to generate square wave AC to heater (to prevent potential electrolysis). Voltage at solar panel is filtered by large capacitor and MCU control PWM duty cycle and maintain desired voltage at solar panel ("MPPT"). I have four panels Vmp=30V (Voc=40V) each with current up to 10A. MCU also measure water temperature and display info (power, duty cycle, temperature, generated energy etc.).  Thanks very low power constuption system is powered directly from solar cells using simple HV linear regulator (no battery or external power supply). "MPPT" Feature helps lot in partly cloudy days. I can share schematic, PCB, and MCU program (AVR128DB28). Moreover it is "optocoupled UART report ready" and it can be powered also from external (galvanicaly isolated DC/DC converter on board) power supply to work (display temperature) in night. Of course any use is at your own risks. My system is tripple protected (temperature sensing by MCU, hardware thermostat, safety valve).
You should definitly read what David writes (especially about disconnecting DC by mechanical switches).
